# After adding a logger (serilog), I no longer receive the error messages associated with 500 errors in the response

Tags: c#, exception, logging, .net-core-3.1

Using .NET Core 3.1 in a non-production environment, I figured the exceptions were at one point being displayed in the body of failed 500 error responses as an added bonus of me using `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`. At some point (possibly after configuring a logger), that was no longer the case and I started having to check the logs to see what error messages were associated with the 500s.  I'd like to reverse this behavior so that the error messages are included within the response body again.

Comment: Difficut to tell withoutt any code.

Comment: Most of the code is the same as the default web api app for .NET Core. Then I'm using an in-house library that configures a lot of different things using reflection, so I'm just broadly asking because I know any given thing could cause this. The main difference is that I've configured Serilog.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't phrase the question correctly - I guess I am asking what is responsible for the functionality that allows a failed endpoint to return the actual exception details. I can walk it backwards to figure out what components may have been added to block that behavior.